# Proguard - How to create multiple output jars with shared input jars

Tags: java, ant, build, proguard

So for example I want each output jar to include both injars just above it:

```
# Windows Client
-injars common.jar
-injars windowsClient.jar
-outjar windowsClient.jar

# Mac Client
-injars common.jar
-injars macClient.jar
-outjar macClient.jar

# Windows Server 
-injars common.jar
-injars windowsServer.jar
-outjar windowsServer.jar

# Mac Server 
-injars common.jar
-injars macServer.jar
-outjar macServer.jar
```

So this works and only includes the code specific for each jar. The problem is that I also get tons of "Duplication of definition of program class" warnings from proguard. I assume it's because of the duplicated `-injars common.jar`, but I don't know how to resolve that. If I remove `-injars common.jar` from each grouping then I get an error about having to use a filter.

Is there a way for example to say:

```
# Windows Server (3 step)
-removeJars macClient.jar
-injars ...
-outjars windowsServer.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard's intention is to ignore duplicate input classes (apart from printing out notes) and to write each processed class to a single jar. You could create a separate output jar for commons.jar and merge it into the other jars later on.

Your trick happens to work, by somewhat inefficiently reading the same commons.jar multiple times. You can suppress the warnings with `-dontnote`.

Notes:

- The names of input jars and output jars must be different.
- You may want to disable class merging (`-optimizations !class/merging/*`), to keep classes from migrating between jars.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this in Proguard 5? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418117/proguard-5-how-to-create-multiple-output-jars-with-shared-input-jars